# How to calculate mean and proportion from a binomial distribution?

Tags: mean, binomial-distribution, proportion

Lets say that I flip a coin and get heads 50/200 times. What would my proportion and mean be for this binomial distribution? I am getting confused, because in a binomial distribution there are only 2 outcomes, so how do you find an average of a categorical variable?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you might be getting confused between sample means and population means. When people write about the "mean" of a binomial distribution, they are refering to the population mean, in other words the expected value of the distribution, which is $np$ where $n$ is the number of trials and $p$ is the probability of a success. If you flip a fair coin 200 times, then $p=0.5$ and the mean (aka expected value) would be 100. The mean is a theoretical quantity -- it's the average number of heads you would get if you tossed the coin 200 times and repeated that an infinite number of times.

Comment: You are confused between a Bernoulli distribution ( 1 coin flip, parameter p=probability) and a Binomial distribution (n coin flips, with parameters p=probability and n=number of flips). the mean of a binomial distribution with 100 flips and p=0.5 is 50 heads.

Answer (score 0):

In your coin flipping example you appear to be interested in the proportion of heads. The proportion of trials resulting in a head is in your example 50/200=.25. If we code a head as 1 (success) and a tails as 0 (failure), then compute the mean, and it will be .25. Lets say the first 10 trials are: heads, heads, tails, tails, tails, heads, tails, tails, tails, tails. So that translates to: 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0. If we compute the mean of that, we first add those 0s and 1s and than divide by the number of trials. Adding 0s and 1s is the same as counting the 1s. So we have 3 success out of 10 trials, that sounds like a proportion...

Comment: Thank you for your reply. After doing a little digging, I found that the mean of a binomial distribution is calculated as X=np, where x is the mean, n is the number of trials (200 coin flips), and p is the probability of success (0.5). Wouldn't the mean be 100 heads, and the proportion be 0.25? Your method also makes sense. I guess I don't understand what a mean represents in a binomial distribution.

Comment: @statsnovice It seems unlikely that $p=0.5$ in your example, unless you know you have a fair coin.